# Computer won't connect to wireless connection

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I have a client that has a Dell Latitude D620 running Windows 7 32 bit. It was previously able to connect to the company wireless, but now doesn't even see any available connections. I have downloaded all of the current drivers. We run ESET anti virus and Barracuda WSA. Other similar computers running the same programs have no issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does your D620 detects other wireless? (Home wireless or other free hotspot wireless etc) If not, then maybe somehow your wireless is dead? (or as what @Darth Android has suggested as answer)

Answer (score 4):

Look for a *physical radio switch*. This might be a sliding switch on the side of the computer, or it might be a key combo like <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> (it will have a radio tower icon). Try toggling this once.

This functionality is common on recent windows-based laptops produced in the past half-decade or so, and is very useful for disabling the wireless chipset when you know you're not going to be using it (like on a plane, for example). This will save battery life.

However, it is also the source of many headaches because it's not always apparent that the radio has been turned off.

---

Your laptop (Dell Latitude D620) should have a sliding switch on the left side, just behind the expresscard slot.

[image: Dell Latitude D620]

Answer (score 0):

There is also a software method of turning the wireless card off:

[image: WIFI card screenshot]

To turn it back on (on Windows XP. Probably the same method in 7), go to Start --> Control Panel --> Click on the icon for your network card, and a screen like shown above should appear.

Also try deleting all WiFi profiles stored in the computer, make sure that the card is set up to receive available networks, and let it look for the connection.

If the PC was already connected to the network before, it is possible that it is already attempting to connect ***without the correct WEP/WPA WiFi password.***

Keep messing around with it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for all of your input, but I have already made sure that the both toggle switches (the one on the side and Fn/F2 are on.  The computer was connected before, but now it doesn't even see any available connections.

Comment: Did you try to delete all wifi profiles, restart, and let it look for connections again? (all this was included with my answer above)